# Jquery live click causing double window opening, can't return false, prevent default, or just get the link to plain stop!

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal

So for the life of me I can't figure out why this isn't working. I have a live click out there for when some one clicks a link. Any link that is external to the website should open in a new tab.  This would in theory work with some drupal views that refresh content via ajax.

Below is the code I've dug up and frankensteined together. It is only grabbing links that link external, that works. It also works on click for them, as the alert fires (removing it changes nothing). The stopImmediatePropogation() does nothing, the preventDefault does nothing, and return false does nothing. The link still GOES!

I just want to sotp the link! I can handle making it open in a new window fine as window.open(this.href) works, just in conjunction with this kid it opens in the current window AND a new window!

```
$("a[href^='http:']:not([href*='" + window.location.host + "'][target='_blank'])").live('click', function(e){
    alert('this is it!');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
    return false;
    //window.open(this.href);
});
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a[href^='http:']:not([href*='" + window.location.host + "'][target='_blank'])").live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href, "_blank");
});
```

Comment: Okay, so you were actually right, however there's a part of the problem I didn't uncover. I'm using drupals google analytics plugin, which allows you to track outbound links. It however does so in a fashion that causes the double opening issue.

Comment: I should've guessed it was something other than my code that caused it.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with my buttons that I set to live.  I ended up using a global variable...essentially a flag boolean that I would check for in each function and then reset at the end of the function....(i.e....global set to false....check for !variable....set to true.....do my stuff....and then set to false again before exiting function)....seems to work so far....